# How to pass value from a control inside a Listview to another control outside

Tags: asp.net, listview, controls

I have a Listview displaying one record at the time. Here is a very simple example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="bol_id" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
<ItemTemplate>
 Textbox inside<asp:TextBox ID="txtInside" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bol_id") %>'></asp:TextBox> 

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
 Textbox Outside<asp:TextBox ID="txtOutside" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

Everything works fine, the Textbox inside the ItemTemplate, gets its data from the database and gets populated. I also have a pager that moves one record at the time without a problem.

Now, I would like to get the Textbox outside the ItemTemplate to get the same value as the Textbox inside. But I do not manage to get it working. When I try this and similar code:

This code is placed in the Code Behind Page Load:

```
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ListView1.FindControl("txtInside"), TextBox)

    txtOutside.Text = tb.Text
```

all I get is the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Anyone, have a good solution how to access this control and pass its value to the other control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.

I kept on trying until I found a solution. This is what I did:

In the ListView part, I added a `OnPreRender` part:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="bol_id" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnPreRender="ListView1_OnPreRender">
```

Then in the Code Behind I added this:

```
Protected Sub ListView1_OnPreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If ListView1.EditIndex > -1 Then
        ' because I need to avoid error when in Edit mode
    Else

        Dim tb As TextBox = Nothing

        For Each item As ListViewDataItem In ListView1.Items

            tb = DirectCast(item.FindControl("txtInsideId"), TextBox)

            If tb.Text IsNot Nothing Then
                txtOutsideId.Text = tb.Text.ToString
            End If
        Next

    End If


End Sub
```

And now it works! Don't know if it is the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

1. Is the ListView in another container control?
2. Is ListView1 returning an instance of the ListView class?
3. Add a button to the form and wire up it's click event to your code. Does it work now? 4. Has data already been bound to the ListView when your code is being called?

These types of error messages can be a bit misleading so I have found it best to start from the beginning and make no assumptions about what is happening.

Good luck!